# JQuery Tablesort with hidden rows?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table which uses the jquery hide() and show() to manipulate the standard view.  However when i include the table sort it only sorts on the visible rows and not the hidden ones.  Is there anyway to get it to sort on all the items?

---

I have just realised that i was setting my class of HIDEME in my xslt which the hide and show functions in my jquery were using.  This meant that my sorter was doing it correctly however i was hiding the data wrong..  So i guess i need to modify my question to...How can i show the first n rows of a table then on the click of an external button show all the other rows.  Then when i do the sort it needs to know what the new order is for when it does the hide/show/

So confusing..can anyone help?

Chris

Comment: You really should move your answer to the question as an update, otherwise people may miss the correction.  But, you have 20 rows, you show 10, are these the first 10 of the sorted 20? If you hide the remaining 10 rows would the viewable results be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to sort with jQuery's functions, but you may find this helpful.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part1

The other option is to just get all the rows yourself and using javascript's `sort` function on the rows, so you can sort in-place, this way you can pick which column or columns to sort on.

But, in any event, when you are finished sorting you will probably need to change the classes again for alternating colors, for each row.